# Making a bubble tooltip overlap its window edges

Tags: javascript, html, css

is it possible for positioned content to overlap the edge of the document window that contains it? E.g. if I have a popup inside a popup, can the latter overlap the window borders of the former?

I have noticed that very long tool-tip bubbles created using the HTML TITLE attribute do overlap, but never seen a CSS or JavaScript bubble that does that.

E.g. this is a pure CSS bubble demo:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/csstooltips/

If I resize the window so that it is quite small and then hover on the second link, I get a long tool-tip that gets clipped against the window, not what I want.

Comment: If you're doing this in an iframe, you may be able to spawn the tooltip in the containing window. Other than that, I think the only way to do this would be using a browser plugin of some kind.

Comment: An interesting question might also be this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511134/html-divs-can-go-outside-browser-window

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's not possible. The tooltip generated by the `title` attribute are created as operating system elements, and are outside of the browser window.

On the other hand, anything you create using Javascript will be part of the web page, and thus contrained by limits of the the browser window.

There is nothing you can do about this. Sorry.

(I note that @easwee's comment links to a question where an answer is given which does provide a solution, however it is an IE-only solution and will break in any other browser)